SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992) - Azure Blob
I am trying to read data from a excel file stored on Azure Blob into a pandas dataframe
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="xxxxxxx", credential='yyyyyyy')
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client('aaaa', blob = 'abc.xlsx')
blob = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
df = pd.read_excel(blob, engine = "openpyxl")

There are intermittent errors for this code. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't for the same piece of code. Its hard to solve this as I am not sure what is causing the issue. The error is as below.
I have checked my VPN connections as well, still not able to resolve it, please help
ServiceRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[69], line 4
      2blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="xxxxxxx", credential='yyyyyyy')
      3 blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client('aaaa', blob = 'abc.xlsx')
----> 4 blob = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
      5 df = pd.read_excel(blob, engine = "openpyxl")
      6 cc = {df.iloc[i, 0] : df.iloc[i, 1] for i in range(df.shape[0])}

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py:78, in distributed_trace..decorator..wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs)
     76 span_impl_type = settings.tracing_implementation()
     77 if span_impl_type is None:
---> 78     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     80 # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed
     81 if merge_span and not passed_in_parent:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py:942, in BlobClient.download_blob(self, offset, length, encoding, **kwargs)
    848 """Downloads a blob to the StorageStreamDownloader. The readall() method must
    849 be used to read all the content or readinto() must be used to download the blob into
    850 a stream. Using chunks() returns an iterator which allows the user to iterate over the content in chunks.
   (...)
    935         :caption: Download a blob.
    936 """
    937 options = self._download_blob_options(
    938     offset=offset,
...
--> 386     raise error
    387 if _is_rest(request):
    388     from azure.core.rest._requests_basic import RestRequestsTransportResponse

ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)



ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)

According to this MS-Document, the error you are seeing is related to a self-signed certificate in the certificate chain.
To resolve, you need to import the certificate into your device by referring to the above document.
Code:
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# Set the path to the certificate file
certificate_path = '/path/to/certificate.cer'

# Set the environment variable for the certificate
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = certificate_path

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client('test', blob='test.xlsx')
blob = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
df = pd.read_excel(blob, engine="openpyxl")
print(df)

Output:

Reference:
Tutorial: Copy to Blob storage via REST APIs - Azure Data Box | Microsoft Learn

Hi venkatesan, how do i get this path? Is it the same for all machines?
certificate_path = '/path/to/certificate.cer'
